# aasm: error in after event callback cancels the event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, aasm

I have an aasm event which looks like this:

```
event :close do
  transitions from: :normal, to: :closed
  after do
    action_1(...)
    action_2(...)
  end
end
```

now, I've noticed that when I call close! and there's an error on action2, the event is not saved in the db. I guess that the order of things is 
1. transition of the instance
2. after callbacks
3. save

except for catching the error under the 'after' block level, is there a callback that is triggered after the 'save' which I can use ?

Comment: Is it possible to use Delayed::Job or something similar in your application?  That would allow you to change action_2 to _queueing_ action_2 (which should always succeed).

Comment: Actually it's a good idea (in fact I was going to queue this action anyway) , I'll have that in mind.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that aasm wraps the save into a transaction, which rolls back on exception.

**Currently there is no callback available for your purpose**, but I could imagine something like

```
event :close do
  transitions from: :normal, to: :closed
  assure do
    action_1(...)
    action_2(...)
  end
end
```

where `action_1` and `action_2` will be executed even in case of an exception.

Please add an issue to the [github repository](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/issues?state=open) and I will take care of that.

Comment: thanks for your help. The truth is that if I only have to worry about a cancelled event it's not a big deal. The real problem here is that action1 already finished (like notifying a user about the change) and then because of action2 the event gets cancelled and that action1 (user notification) is not relevant anymore..